# Flash Builder 4.7 corrupt workspaces

Tags: flash-builder, corruption

On OS 10.8.2 and using the latest Flash Builder 4.7 it seems I can't go for more than a few days before running into compile errors.

90% of the time these have something to do with my workspace becoming corrupt.

Simple to fix, BUT, a pain having to reapply ALL my settings, plugins etc every time I create a NEW workspace.

Can anyone suggest any way(s) of avoiding workspaces from becoming corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Great question, I really hope someone can answer it. In the meantime, I found a way to recover from crashes without needing to rebuild all the project configuration etc which is so tedious. This is on OSX 10.8.4, Flash Builder 4.5, hopefully it works for FB 4.7 too...

- Ensure FB is closed
- Move all the project files out of the {workspace_fb}.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects folder.
- Start FB then close it again.
- Move projects folders back in to the .projects folder.
- Start FB.